Tikzplotlib module throws attribute error: module 'webcolors' has no attribute 'CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES'
I would like to convert matplotlib figures to PGFPlots/Tikz figures while using the module tikzplotlib:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tikzplotlib

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 51)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

tikzplotlib.save('test.tex')

When I run this code, I get an attribute error:
AttributeError: module 'webcolors' has no attribute 'CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES'

The documentations of tikzplotlib and webcolors did not give me an idea to solve this.
I have found related questions(1, 2) to the described attribute error from the webcolors module without a solution for me.
Is someone able to reproduce this error or knows a solution for this?
I am working with python 3.9.5, webcolors 24.6.0 and tikzplotlib 0.10.1 in Visual Studio Code Version 1.90.2 on Windows 11.

tikzplotlib is no longer regularly maintained, so it may be best to clone/fork it and update a local copy.
The offending line is for h, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items(): in /src/tikzplotlib/_color.py.  For webcolors 24.8.0, you can replace this line with
for name in webcolors.names('css3'):
    h = webcolors.name_to_hex(name)


Solved:
The module webcolors had recent changes and the attributes for the mapping of color names/values is no longer publically accessible.
Since tikzplotlib has not been updated to this changes, an older version (e.g. version 1.13) of webcolors must be used.
